# Recovering data from zfs pool with deleted partition tables

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery, raid, zfs

I was consolidating the hard drives from two nas's into one nas and when I put the hard drives from the second nas into the new enclosure, my raid card wiped the partition tables for all the connected drives.
The 5 drives I was adding had previously been hardware raid-5 formatted with ext4
The 5 drives that were already in the nas had been zfs raidz.
Both sets of drives had nearly identical data as I had mirrored them before doing this.
The system is running Ubuntu Server.
Is there any way to recover the data on either set of drives?
I figure that recovering the partition table's on the zfs pool should be possible but I can't find a resource on how.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I suspect the answers you seek relate mostly to the RAID card(s) in those devices; and not the Ubuntu OS that sent the data to those NAS devices.

Comment: the data i think is most likely recoverable was a zfs pool in ubuntu. The raid card is out of the picture at this point. The ubuntu os is acting as a NAS.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ubuntu , it is not an Ubuntu problem or something similar .

Comment: This question is on topic because it's also about Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding a reddit thread covering how to do this.
It involved rebuilding the partition tables using `sgdisk` after figuring out where all the partitions should have gone. this was done by looking at the partition table for a zfs drive of the same model since it seems that zfs partitions drives in a very predictable manner.

In my case, the command was:

`sgdisk -n1:2048:15628036095 -t1:BF01 -n9:15628036096:15628052479 -t9:BF07 <device>`

which had to be run on every drive that had been part of the array after which `zpool import <pool name>` was able to work and restore the array.

credit to fields_g on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/zfs/comments/d6v47t/deleted_disk_partition_tables_of_a_zfs_pool/f17yt5s/